# Handling access denied result

Tags: 8, http-request, event-subscribers

In Drupal 8, what is the correct way of returning access denied to a user (outside of access requirement on a controller)?

I'd say it is to throw an `AccessDeniedHttpException` most of the time, but I have seen modules set an event response to `403`, or do a redirect response to `system.403`.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, the correct way is to `throw new AccessDeniedHttpException()` over setting a 403 or a redirect response, which bypasses the exception handling, so that it's no longer possible to configure a different handling of 403's in contrib or custom code. Unless you want to bypass this intentionally, for example if you want to produce a faster 403.

However, in most cases it is preferable to control the access as route requirement. The main effect is the same, the routing system throws an exception as well. But it does other things, like controlling the visibility of menu links, which you don't get when you throw the exception in custom code.

Comment: So if you are responding to an Event (onRequest), its fine to do a RedirectResponse to system.403 over throw an exception? An exception seems to make more sense to me.

Comment: Yes, the exception does make more sense. Then the default exception handler can set the 403 response for `system.403`, without a redirect, but with a subrequest keeping the original URL in the address bar.